# Use PHP to replicate grids like row-grid.js or collagePlus to arrange images server-side

Tags: php, image, variables, grid, row

I hope the title is descriptive enough.

I've used [jQuery row-grid.js](https://github.com/brunjo/rowGrid.js) a couple times. It works fine. I would like to do the arranging server-side instead, for obvious reasons. I assumed there must be something to do this with PHP. I know how I would approach it and get the job done but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Apparently I'm not using the right search terms because I come up empty.

Here is an example of row-grid.js's work:

http://www.ericdunlap.com/stuff/sample-grid.jpg

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Javascript code used in the plugin, and rewrite it in PHP.

Comment: Golly! I never thought of that! Thanks!